# What inspired the toxic blood?

Tags: behind-the-scenes, the-x-files

I had always assumed that the green and highly toxic alien blood in *The X-Files* was inspired by the yellow and highly acidic alien blood in *Alien*.

[image]

However, I was recently told that *X-Files* creator Chris Carter had in fact been inspired by an ***actual human medical case***.

Some research online shows that this claim is supported by many fans.

**Is this true and supported by an authoritative statement?**

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the blood in the X-Files as well as an episode of Greys Anatomy was inspired, as you say, by a real life story, that of [Gloria Ramirez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloria_Ramirez).

> Gloria Ramirez was a Riverside, California, woman dubbed "the toxic lady" by the media when several Riverside General Hospital workers became ill after exposure to her body and blood. Her case was the basis for a scene in one episode of the American TV series The X-Files, an episode of the American TV drama Grey's Anatomy, a segment of a show on Discovery Communications' channel Investigation Discovery called "The New Detectives, a third season episode of Weird or What?, the "Stink Bomb" segment of the animated film Memories and an episode of Law & Order.

The article only mentions one episode of the X-Files - [The Erlenmeyer Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Erlenmeyer_Flask) so it's possible that what you heard was indirect relationship to that or, more likely, the Wikipedia article doesn't take further episodes into account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Do you have a specific official reference (other than Wikipedia)?